randomPoints function not working on bioclim data
I want to use bioclim variables in my species distribution model but am having issues with the randomPoints function from dismo. I get the error:

Error in randomPoints(bats_buff_final, 1000, bats_max) :    generated
random points = 0.052 times requested number; Use a higher value for
tryf

I simplified matters by using only one raster rather than a raster stack and that's the elevation data available here (just beware it's > 300 MB if you want to download it) https://geodata.ucdavis.edu/climate/worldclim/2_1/base/wc2.1_30s_elev.zip
The solution offered here hasn't worked for me.
library(usdm)
library(dismo)
library(sf)
library(terra)
library(tidyverse)

# load the bioclim data
    alt = raster("data/wc2.1_30s_elev/wc2.1_30s_elev.tif")

# load the map
    
    africa1 <- rnaturalearth::ne_countries(scale = "medium", returnclass = "sf", continent = 'africa')
    africa <- st_as_sf(africa1 %>% filter(!admin %in% c("Comoros", "Madagascar", "Cape Verde")), crs = 4326) %>% # remove islands
      st_crop(c(xmin=-20, xmax= 52, ymin= -36, ymax= 37))               
   
# load the points
    bats_max <- structure(list(Longitude = c(12.3667, 13, 11.9667, 10.8167, 11.3733, 
    17.157, 16.2337, 16.3333, 23.78, 22.45, 18.9, 27.3, 18.91, 20.8833, 
    20.8333, 23.783, 19.2, 28.5, 28.45, 26.55, 22.43, 28.467, 25.2333, 
    20.33, 29.133, 25.283, 32.954), Latitude = c(3.2167, 3, 2.9833, 
    2.7833, 3.9168, 3.898, 2.9854, 3.6, -6.8, -5.8, -5.05, 2.4167, 
    -5.08, 0.2413, 0.2333, 1.3, -0.33, 1.3833, -1.9, -4.533, -5.88, 
    -1.9, 0.55, -1.35, 3.913, 1.283, 0.4373)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
    27L))    
    
# create buffers and sample around them with the env layer
    bats_max_p <- SpatialPoints(bats_max, proj4string=CRS("+proj=longlat +ellps=WGS84 +datum=WGS84 +no_defs"))
    bats_buff <- buffer(bats_max_p,1000000)  # adds a buffer (in meters), that will be used to create the "study area" for background points
    bats_buff1 <- crop(bats_buff, africa)  # crop out areas out in the ocean
    bats_buff2 <- rasterize(bats_buff1, alt) # convert to raster (for later use to select background points - ie random pseudo-absence points)
    bats_buff_final <- mask(bats_buff2, alt) # mask buffer to ensure that it has same extent as enviro layers
    
    backg1 <- randomPoints(bats_buff_final, 1000, bats_max)  # NB - changed to 1000 for preliminary run


Try dismo::randomPoints(bats_buff_final, 1000, bats_max, tryf = 100).

Thanks very much, that did the job. I was increasing n, the number of points and not tryf. If you'd like to put this as an answer I can mark it as correct.

The thing is to increase tryf parameter of randomPoints() function as there is more cells with NA than those with 1 in bats_buff_final layer (in fact it covers whole globe, which probably is not necessary at all).
[... your code]

backg1 <- randomPoints(bats_buff_final, 1000, bats_max, tryf = 100)

backg1[1:10,]
#>              x          y
#>  [1,] 20.48750 -10.429167
#>  [2,] 26.91250 -13.387500
#>  [3,] 11.16250  12.304167
#>  [4,] 17.37917 -10.220833
#>  [5,] 33.03750   8.187500
#>  [6,] 19.33750  -2.862500
#>  [7,] 27.37083 -11.587500
#>  [8,] 20.39583  -8.829167
#>  [9,] 20.11250  -3.870833
#> [10,] 13.52917   7.695833

terra::plot(terra::vect(africa))
terra::plot(bats_buff_final, add = TRUE, legend = FALSE)
terra::plot(terra::vect(backg1, crs = "+proj=longlat +ellps=WGS84 +datum=WGS84 +no_defs"), pch = 16, cex = 0.4, add = TRUE)


Created on 2024-10-03 with reprex v2.1.0
